# There's a error with sonar.sources how can i fix that?

Tags: sonarqube

What I got is this error...I'm new to sonarqube.. I don't know how to fix that.... I also tried adding src as the source. But it doesn't work...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\____>cd C:\Users\_____\Desktop\ITPM_SonarqubeSampleProject

C:\Users\____\Desktop\ITPM_SonarqubeSampleProject>sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonarScanner\sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492- 
windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.3.0.1492
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\_____\.sonar\cache
INFO: SonarQube server 7.6.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=126ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AWmFD6wOR7iN1xXjam-4
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\_____\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=84ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=225ms
INFO: Process project properties
ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.sources for ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3.105s
INFO: Final Memory: 6M/162M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: The folder 'ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject/src' does not exist for 'ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject' (base directory = C:\Users\____\Desktop\ITPM_SonarqubeSampleProject)
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

C:\Users\_____\Desktop\ITPM_SonarqubeSampleProject>
```

what I add to the sonar-scanner.properties.

```
 sonar.projectKey = ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject
 sonar.projectName = ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject
 sonar.projectVersion = 1.0
 sonar.sources = c:/ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject/src/itpm_sonarqubesampleproject
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not clear why you are in the `C:\Users\____\Desktop\ITPM_SonarqubeSampleProject` directory and defining sonar.sources as `c:/ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject/src/itpm_sonarqubesampleproject`.

Second, the last line below indicates that you don't have a `sonar-scanner.properties` in the current folder:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonarScanner\sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492- 
windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
```

I suggest that you add this file in your project and set these properties on it (and not on the sonar-scanner.properties from the sonar-scanner installation).

After, if you're inside the `C:\Users\____\Desktop\ITPM_SonarqubeSampleProject` directory when you run the sonar-scanner and considering that your source code is there, you can just set `sonar.sources=.`. You don't need to use the absolute path.

Comment: If I add 
C:/ITMP_SonarqubeSampleProject/src/itpm_sonarqubesampleproject as source?